# Visual studio code keep showing unecesarry error

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, eloquent, controller, laravel-8

I dont know why the error message keep showing in my problem tab

**This screenshot my vscode**
[image]

that message show after adding method destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Auth::user()` return type is not the `User` model instance. And that's why it's shown as error. You can use comment to define the variable as an instance of the `User` model like,

```
/** @var User $ketua */
$ketua = Auth::user();
```

Answer (score 3):

If the code is working fine, then it's just your ide complaining.

Please try the following package:

```
composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
```

then run:

```
php artisan ide-helper:generate
```

This package will then install the necessary files for your ide.

Note: You will need to run generate command whenever you have new package installed to avoid error from your ide.

[more on ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Answer (score 0):

Intelephense extension is checking for Undefined Methods, if you don't want that warning Add this line in your vs code settings.json file.

```
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false
```